# Проверить и нажать на кнопку внутри flash через selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui

Для примера возьмем сайт с игрой
https://igroutka.ru/flesh-igry/31608-schenok-na-avtomoyke.html
Там flash нужно сделать поиск по картинке и нажать с помощью python selenium типо как pyautogui только в selenium

[image: Скриншот будет для поиска то что в красном квадрате]

Comment: насколько я знаю, нет возможности взаимодействовать с _flash_ элементами с помощью ```selenium```. Если вы собираетесь распознавать изображение, а я именно так понял "_Там flash нужно сделать поиск по картинке_",то вообще нет смысла использовать ```selenium``` для последующего клика по координатам найденного элемента

Comment: Мне именно нужна поиск по картинке работа с flash мне не нужно просто для примера я показал, не нужно работать с селектором а потом когда уже откроется flash игра работать с картинками... А какой посоветуешь библиотеку для работы с картинками? чтоб можно на несколько браузеров одновременно запускать